# Python Pandas: Confirm if a substring of DataFrame A is part of a string in DataFrame B

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, find

I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

countries_list_a = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['Australia', 'United Kingdom', 'United States'], 'Code' : ['A', 'B', 'C']})

countries_list_b = pd.DataFrame ({'Name' : ['Jack', 'Maria', 'David'], 'Geo' : ['New York, United States', 'Sydney, Australia', 'London, United Kingdom']})
```

And i want to check iteratively if a string in each cell of a specific column of `countries_list_a`, can be found in any cell of a specific column of `countries_list_b`.

More specifically these are the columns:

```
countries_list_a["Country"]
countries_list_b["Geo"]
```

And i want to check iteratively if a string in each cell of `countries_list_a["Country"]` can be
found in any cell of `countries_list_b["Geo"]`. It is important to note that i need to keep track of the indices and store them separately in an array. If i try to verify the presence of the string manually like that:

```
tmp_country_a = countries_list_a["Country"][0]
tmp_country_b = countries_list_b["Geo"][1]

if (tmp_country_a in tmp_country_b):
 print ("Correct")
```

everything works fine. Of course doing this process manually is not an option.

If i try to build a loop like that:

```
index_a = np.size(countries_list_a["Country"])
index_b = np.size(countries_list_b["Geo"])

for i in range(index_a):
 tmp_country_a = countries_list_a["Country"][i]
 for j in range(index_b):
  tmp_country_b = countries_list_b["Geo"][j]
  if (tmp_country_a in tmp_country_b):
   print("Correct")
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) of your input DataFrames and the matching expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Given the shown format, wouldn't it be better to extract the part of the string that if after the last `,` in `countries_list_b['Geo']`? This would give a direct match.

Comment: Also, since you mention wanting to keep track of the indices, what is your ultimate goal? Can you have multiple matches? Do you want to `merge` the dataframes?

Comment: About the second comment, this is a simplified example of the column. There is no specific order and a cell can be like: `'Orlando, FL, United States'` , or `Idaho, Moscow, United States of America`. So i need to check for the string. About the third comment, I need to know in which line is every country for the given order of the column

Comment: Can you update your example to reflect this more complex format, and if this is an eventuality, add a duplicate to see how this should be handled. Don't forget to provide the expected output given the provided input.

Comment: So i found the mistake...Thank you for your time and i apologize for the inconvenience. The above example is correct. The problem was that i was loading the dataframes from .csv files and if there was no country corresponding to the name of a person, the cell value was `0`. So in the loop, without understanding it i was comparing `strings` to `ints` for certain iterations. I had to open and check all the entries in the .csv files to understand that. The correct statement is `if (str(tmp_country_a) in str(tmp_country_b)):`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

countries_list_a = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['Australia', 'United Kingdom', 'United States'], 'Code' : ['A', 'B', 'C']})
#         Country Code
#       Australia    A
#  United Kingdom    B
#  United States     C
countries_list_b = pd.DataFrame ({'Name' : ['Jack', 'Maria', 'David'], 'Geo' : ['New York, United States', 'Sydney, Australia', 'London, United Kingdom']})
 #  Name                      Geo
 # Jack  New York, United States
 # Maria        Sydney, Australia
 # David   London, United Kingdom

geo = countries_list_b.Geo
countries_list_a["country_found"] = [any(country in g for g in geo) for country in countries_list_a.Country]

# print(countries_list_a)
#         Country Code  country_found
#       Australia    A           True
#  United Kingdom    B           True
#  United States     C           True
```